# Different probability for each case but still able to get answer

Tags: combinatorics

Box 1 has five balls (White1,White2,Black1,Black2,Black3).

Box 2 has eight balls (Red1,Red2,Red3,Red4,Red5,Green1,Green2,Green3).

Box 3 has seven balls (Red6,Red7,Red8,Red9,Green4,Green5,Green6).

We first start by drawing a ball from Box 1.

If a white ball is drawn, we proceed to draw two balls without replacement from Box 2.

If a black ball is drawn, we proceed to draw two balls without replacement from Box 3.

Let $M$ be the event of obtaining one red ball and one green ball. Let us consider two methods of finding $P(M)$.

Method 1. (Correct Method) We note that the probability of drawing a particular case with a white ball, say White1,Red1,Green1 is $\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{1}{8}\times\frac{1}{7}=\frac{1}{280}$.

We note that the probability of drawing a particular case with a black ball, say Black1,Red6,Green4 is $\frac{1}{5}\times\frac{1}{7}\times\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{210}$.

Then $P(M)=\frac{2\times5\times3+2\times3\times5}{280}+\frac{3\times4\times3+3\times3\times4}{210}=\frac{39}{70}$.

Method 2. (Wrong Method) $P(M)=\frac{\text{total number of cases with one red and one green}}{\text{total number of possible cases}}=\frac{2\times5\times3+2\times3\times5+3\times4\times3+3\times3\times4}{2\times8\times7+3\times7\times6}=\frac{66}{119}$.

So my question is, can we modify the number of balls in Boxes 2 and 3 such that these two boxes do not have the same number of balls but yet, $P(M)$ is the same using both of the above methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $R_2, G_2$ and $T_2$ be the number of red balls, green balls and total balls in Box $2$, and let $R_3, G_3$ and $T_3$ be defined similarly. Then what you're trying to find is a solution to the equation

$$\frac{4R_2G_2}{5T_2(T_2-1)} + \frac{6R_3G_3}{5T_3(T_3-1)} = \frac{4R_2G_2 + 6R_3G_3}{2T_2(T_2-1)+3T_3(T_3-1)}$$

A bunch of tedious algebra 'simplifies' this to

$$R_2G_2T_3(T_3-1) = R_3G_3T_2(T_2-1)$$

but this is still a diophantine equations with 4 unknowns (since $T_k = R_k + G_k$) and I don't see a way to determine solutions in general. I did try my luck using $T_2=8$ and $T_3=7$ and found **a** solution pretty quickly:

Box $2$ : $\quad \quad \quad 4$ red, $4$ green

Box $3$ : $\quad \quad \quad 3$ red, $4$ green

I would imagine you could find solutions for other totals similarly with just a little trial and error.

Comment: Thank you so much! In my work I actually obtained the first equation as well. However, my notation was poor so I gave up simplifying it. I really admire your choice of notation and determination to simplify until the second equation. I guess your hardwork gave you luck when a general solution wasn't clear.